# search with ror

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, pagination

ok here is my problem. i make a simple search with title.
it work but with paginate dont!

```
contollers>store_controller

class StoreController < ApplicationController
  def index

  @buildings = Building.search(params[:search])

  @buildings = Building.paginate :page=>params[:page], :order =>'created_at DESC', :per_page=>10

 end

end
```

model>building

```
  def self.search(search)
  if search

    find(:all, :conditions => ['title LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
   else
    find(:all)
  end
end
```

views>store

```
 <% if notice%>
<p id="notice"> <%= notice%></p>
<%end%>

<h1>All Priorities</h1>

 <%= form_tag  store_path, :method => 'get'  do %>
<p>
  <%=text_field_tag :search , params[:search]%>
  <%= submit_tag "Search", :name=> nil%>
  </p>
  <%end%>


<% @buildings.each do |building| %>
<div class="entry">
    <div class="img">
    <%= image_tag (building.photo.url)%></div>
    <div class=" disc">
    <h3>Name of the Bulding:  <%= building.title %></h3>
     <h4>Status: <%= building.status %></h4>
    Info: <%=sanitize(building.description)%>
    <div class="price_line">
        <span class="price">Price: <%= sprintf("€ %0.02f",building.price)%></span><br/>
        <div class="button">
        <%= button_to("I want to see it", {:controller => "seeits", :action => "new", :building_id => building.id})%></div>


    </div>

    <div class="pages">
<%= will_paginate @buildings %></p>
</div>

    </div>

</div>


<%end%>
```

controllers>building

```
class BuildingsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /buildings
  # GET /buildings.json
  def index 

    @buildings = Building.all

      respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @buildings }
    end

  end
```

if i have it this way the search does not work and shows me all the buildings. but if i remove from views>store  :

```
<div class="pages">
    <%= will_paginate @buildings %></p>
    </div>
```

and from  contollers>store_controller : 
 `@buildings = Building.paginate :page=>params[:page], :order =>'created_at DESC', :per_page=>10`

it work fine! but i want to paginate when the user is on first side and doesn't do search

UPDATE 1

controllers>store

```
class StoreController < ApplicationController
   def index


    # load @buildings following authorizations, whatever...
    # for instance, if you use cancan and load_and_authorize_resource, you'll have
    # already a @buildings you'd want to use, otherwise load them
    @buildings = Building.all
    # or @buildings = current_user.buildings or whatever makes sense

    @buildings = @buildings.search(params[:search]) if params[:search].present?

    @buildings = @buildings.paginate(:page=>params[:page],
                                     :order =>'created_at DESC',
                                     :per_page=>10)
    # do things, render etc...
  end

end
```

models>building

```
class Building < ActiveRecord::Base
 scope :search, lambda { |text| where('buildings.title LIKE ?', "%#{text}%") }

end
```

the problem remains! error: undefined method `paginate' for #

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to paginat the results of the search, don't paginate again the whole `Building` table!

```
class StoreController < ApplicationController
  def index

    # load @buildings following authorizations, whatever...
    # for instance, if you use cancan and load_and_authorize_resource, you'll have
    # already a @buildings you'd want to use, otherwise load them
    # or @buildings = current_user.buildings or whatever makes sense

    @buildings ||= Building.scoped

    @buildings = @buildings.search(params[:search]) if params[:search].present?

    @buildings = @buildings.paginate(:page=>params[:page],
                                     :order =>'created_at DESC',
                                     :per_page=>10)
    # do things, render etc...
  end

end
```

and, that `search` classmethod is in fact a scope:

```
class Building < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :search, lambda { |text| where('buildings.title LIKE ?', "%#{text}%") }
end
```

Comment: NoMethodError in StoreController#index
undefined method `paginate' for nil:NilClass
app/controllers/store_controller.rb:8:in `index'

Comment: You have to load the buildings before, I'll edit the response. I just skipped it because the buildings may come from an associations or from whatever makes sense.

Comment: still remain the same error. i have update the post take a look

Comment: Could you check that your controller and model correspond to what I wrote in the answer?

Comment: NoMethodError in StoreController#index 
undefined method `paginate' for #<Array:0x6b20f20> app/controllers/store_controller.rb:12:in `index'

Comment: Controllers are unrelated, you can't expect that the BuildingsController have any remote effect on the store views. Modify the StoreController as indicated, and let me know the result. Don't print @buildings before applying the `paginate` method, or it will be converted to an Array.

Comment: i have change only the StoreController as you show me. the Building < ActiveRecord::Base is the same as i show on my question and still the same error

Comment: That's because `find` returns an array, and a scope returns an Relation instance, over which you can apply further scopes and filters.

Comment: Sorry, Building.all also returns an Array. Updated answer has fallback at any step, so if no scope has been applied, you use the class, otherwise you use the already scoped relation.

Comment: Or use `@buildings ||= Building.scoped` to just use an "unscoped" scope.

Comment: i have one more question. is there a way if did not match with some building show some msg like "does not much try another name" ?

Comment: use `<% if @buildings.present? %> <% @buildings.each do |building| %> .... <% end %> <% else %> not found <% end %>`.